# Get Attribute Name in For Loop

Tags: python, django

How do I get the attribute names and values of an object? I'm attempting to cast it to a dictionary so that I can easily JSON serialize the object.

Code:

```
class User:
    ...
    def to_dict( self ):
        dict = {}
        for key, value in filter( lambda aname: not aname.startswith('_'), dir(self) ):
            dict[key] = value
    return dict
```

Error:

```
too many values to unpack
```

Use:

```
user = User({
    's_email': 'bob@email.com',
    's_password': 'password',
})
user.to_dict()
# JSON Serialize
```

Comment: What is the output of `print len(self.__dict__.keys())`?  Add to the first line of `to_dict()` method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.__dict__`. It is a dictionary representing the namespace of the object.

```
class User:
    ...
    def to_dict(self):
        return dict(
            [(k, v) for k, v in self.__dict__.iteritems() if not k.startswith('_')]
        )
```

Note that given your code snippet, the dict returned by `.to_dict()` would contain the key `'to_dict'` as the function does not start with an underscore. Probably a simple mistake in your post.

If the list of attributes that you want to include in the returned dict is small (and doesn't change much), I suggest being explicit about it and listing them

```
class User(object):
    data_attributes = ('s_email', 's_password')
    def to_dict(self):
        return dict([(attr, getattr(self, attr) for attr in self.data_attributes])
```

Answer (score 4):

You get that error because `filter( lambda aname: not aname.startswith('_'), dir(u) )` returns a list of single items, and you are trying to unpack two values (`for key, value`). One potential reason to use `dir` instead of `__dict__` might be that you care about class attrs, or inherited attrs. Since `__dict__` only contains instance attrs it won't find those.

```
class Base(object):
    x = 1

class User(Base):
    y = 2
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.z = z

>>> u = User(3)

>>> u.__dict__
<<< {'z': 3}
```

If you wanted to use `dir` still, you can do so like this:

```
def to_dict(self):
    d = {}
    for k, v in [(x, getattr(self, x)) for x in dir(self) if not x.startswith('_')]:
        if not hasattr(v, '__call__'): d[k] = v # skip methods
    return d

>>> u = User(3)

>>> u.to_dict()
<<< {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

Defining the attributes explicitly [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283809/get-attribute-name-in-for-loop/6283877#6283877) would probably be the best route, though.

Comment: In this case I only need the instance attrs, but this is a good thing to note because I will no doubt use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but why not simply `user.__dict__`?

Comment: Because that would include entries that start with `_` ?

Comment: One reason to not use `__dict__` would be that it only includes instance attributes, and you might care about inherited or class attributes.